# when I open my react website in the localhost, all the css disappears

Tags: css, reactjs, npm

I've made a project based on react and when I open my react website on the localhost, all the css properties doesn't show up. Rest other functionalities are working as usual and all the react logic, but the css effect is missing. It looks plain. I'm showing the image of localhost for example.

[image]

And this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-avatar-edit": "^0.9.0",
    "react-css-modules": "^4.7.11",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-images": "^1.1.7",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-scripts-scss-ts": "^2.17.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.4",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
  }
}
```

**Please help me locate the error**

Comment: How do you include your CSS?

Comment: Can you put the actual code here? did you miss the import of scss file in your jsx/tsx component file?